# Problen in angularjs http.get with params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters, http-get

i have some problem when i used params in http.get. i can't get data from http
this my JS

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, kaka, $ionicPopup,  $http){
 $scope.item ={};
              $scope.code = {};
              $scope.sizes = [ {code: 123456789, name: 'Modul 1'}, {code: 864369038796946, name: 'Modul 4'},
                                {code: 864369038803833, name: 'Modul 5'}, {code: 864369038816645, name: 'Modul 6'},
                                {code: 864369038797142, name: 'Modul 7'}, {code: 864369038796698, name: 'Modul 8'}];
                $scope.update = function(selected) {
                   $scope.item = selected;
                };
 var config = {
                    params: {
                        tN: "find",
                        f12: +$scope.item.code
                    }
                };

                $http.get('http://192.168.100.13:88/OMG1/web.php', config)
               // $http.get('http://192.168.100.13:88/OMG1/web.php?tN=find&f12=123456789')
                  .success(function(data, status, headers,config){
                    console.log('data success');
                    console.log(data); // for browser console
                    $scope.result = data; // for UI
                  })
                  .error(function(data, status, headers,config){
                    console.log('data error');
                  })
                  .then(function(result){
                    things = result.data;
                  });
                  $scope.result = {};
                $scope.findbtn = function () {
                    var lat = parseFloat($scope.result.latitude);
                    var lng = parseFloat($scope.result.longitude);
                    var mylatlng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                        zoom: 15,
                        center: {lat: -7.3342266, lng: 112.7650341},
                        //center: {lat: data[0].lat, lng: data[0].lng},
                        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
                    });
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: mylatlng,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Your Motor'
                    });
                };
})
```

my problem when i use `params` with `f12: +$scope.item.code`in crome debugger i look in `$scope.result` show error `Undefined variable : msg` but if i change params `f12` to `f12:"123456789"` it work correctly .
i don't know how to fix it, p

Comment: I think your question is different.. your problem is variable not assigning properly to a variable.. if thats the case..please try to create a plunkr

Comment: why do you need + symbol in front of you $scope.item.code in f12?

Comment: Right..without + also it should work, but this + is not a problem.. I have created a plunkr foryou.. where it works.. you can fork this plunkr to let us know what is not working.
https://plnkr.co/edit/QaZc523WxjP5maD0jD9j?p=preview

Comment: sorry i can't make plunker, if in params i use  f12= +$scope.item.code error in http and show Undefined variable : msg , but if i use f12="123456789" it work correctly

Comment: i want my url like this http://192.168.100.13:88/OMG1/web.php?tN=find&f12=123456789

Comment: Is your update function get triggered before your RestApi Call? because it's mandatory to assign value before RestApi Call to your $scope.item which is happening in your update function only. If it is happening then log your $scope.item.code in console and let me know what is the result.

Comment: log from $scope.item.code is code for sizes ex. 123456789

Comment: $http.get('your-url', config.params)